# saving jupyter notebook/python files on ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fhs

I have a jupyter notebook with python code and am wondering if it needs to go to a specific file location in Ubuntu? Is there a best practice as to where to put it? Does it not matter?

For example, I place my html/css code in `/var/www/html` in ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "recommended" directory as in case of hosted websites that are placed under `/var/www/html`. It is more of a personal preference.

I personally use a subdirectory under /`home/username` to organizes all my codes files with separate folders for each project.

Comment: can you share why that folder? as in, is it a place where one puts specifically, code files in?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "windows subsystem for Linux." I recommend :

1. Create a folder in /mnt/c/my_notebook_folder. You can also access this folder from windows c:\my_notebook_folder
2. Initialize a git repo and checking the code to GitHub/bitbucket or source control of your choice.